# css media width rule

Tags: html, css, browser

On my site I have

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    document.title = $(window).width();
});
```

When I resize it to 464 firebug reports the layout being `480px`. Why? because of line 8 of my css rule.

```
@media (min-width:481px) {
...
    .class p { width: 480px; } //line 8
}
```

Chrome does the exact same thing (right on 464 as well). Why is this happening? I tried measuring everything to get the exact width until I want to change my css but this strangeness is ruining my measurements

-edit- I did 480-464 to get 16 and add 16 to my width value. It was close. +18 is exactly the measurement i wanted. Do those numbers mean anything to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I tried to get the document width by:

In webkit browsers:

```
$(window).width()
```

In other browsers:

```
Math.max($(window).width(), window.innerWidth)
```

will always get you the width without scrollbar in any browser. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8501499/1121982)